# Create directed random graph specifing alpha of power-law degree distribution

Tags: r, igraph

I have a real directed graph for which I know the number of nodes and edges. The degree distribution approximates a power-law distribution. Now I want to create a random graph replicating the following features of my real graph:

- Number of nodes
- Number of edges
- (Similar) power-law indegree and out
  distribution

Let's assume `g` is my real graph of 10000 nodes and 30000 edges

```
exp.out = 2.2
exp.in = 2.3

set.seed(123)
g <- static.power.law.game(10000, 30000, exp.out, exp.in, multiple=TRUE)
```

Yet I don't know `exp.out` and `exp.in`. Then I try to estimate the power-law exponents with the `plfit` function ([downloaded here](http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/~aaronc/powerlaws/plfit.r)):

```
plfit(degree(g, mode="in")+1)

# $xmin
# [1] 5
# 
# $alpha
# [1] 2.97
# 
# $D
# [1] 0.01735342

plfit(degree(g, mode="out")+1)

# $xmin
# [1] 5
# 
# $alpha
# [1] 2.83
# 
# $D
# [1] 0.01589222
```

From which I then derive my distribution functions (respectively for indegree and outdegree):

- p(x) ~ x^-2.97 for x >= 5
- p(x) ~ x^-2.83 for x >= 5

According to the [documentation](http://igraph.org/r/doc/static.power.law.game.html) of `static.power.law.game`

> The game simply uses static.fitness.game with appropriately
>   constructed fitness vectors. In particular, the fitness of vertex i is
>   i^(-alpha), where alpha = 1/(gamma-1) and gamma is the exponent given
>   in the arguments

As far as I understand it, to replicate my alphas I should pass as gammas respectively 1.3367 (2.97=1/(x-1)) and 1.35336 (2.83=1/(x-1)). Then

```
set.seed(321)
random.g <- static.power.law.game(10000, 30000, 1.35336, 1.3367, multiple=TRUE)
# Error in .Call("R_igraph_static_power_law_game", no.of.nodes, no.of.edges,  : 
#                  At games.c:3748 : out-degree exponent must be >= 2, Invalid value
```

Yet the fact that `static.power.law.game` only takes degree exponents higher then or equal to 2 makes me think that probably I am missing something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exp_out` and `exp_in` should simply be the desired exponent of the out-degree and in-degree distributions, there is no need to do any transformations on the exponents you have obtained from `plfit`. However, note that it is unlikely that you will recover your "observed" exponents exactly due to finite size effects

Comment: But then I don't get  `i^(-alpha), where alpha = 1/(gamma-1)` from documentation... What does it stand for?

Comment: `static.power.law.game` is a convenience wrapper around `static.fitness.game`, and `i^{-alpha}` defines the fitness score of vertex i in `static.fitness.game` - but you shouldn't be concerned with that as you should be specifying the desired exponent (gamma) as a parameter of `static.power.law.game` and it takes care of converting them to the right fitness (alpha) values.